# Plupload : error “code”: 100, “message”: "Failed to open temp directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, plupload

So I am working on a project with plupload/codeigniter. I have the code for custom upload.php in the controller under a function called upload. The javascript for plupload is embedded in the view. But I have tried several variations on the $targetDir without success.

The script can't open the temp directory. I tried to CHMOD 755 on the directories without success. Its still on a local enviroment on my Mac.

```
function upload() {

    // HTTP headers for no cache etc
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    // Settings
    //$targetDir = SITE_DIR . 'nfsopslag/klachten/';
    //$targetDir = SITE_WEB_DIR . 'nfsopslag/klachten/';
    //$targetDir = '..'. SITE_WEB_DIR . 'nfsopslag/klachten/';
    $targetDir = "../../../nfsopslag/klachten";

    $cleanupTargetDir = false; // Remove old files
    $maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

    // 5 minutes execution time
    @set_time_limit(5 * 60);

    // Uncomment this one to fake upload time
    // usleep(5000);

    // Get parameters
    $chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
    $chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
    $fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

    // Clean the fileName for security reasons
    $fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);

    // Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
    if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {
        $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
        $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
        $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

        $count = 1;
        while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b))
            $count++;

        $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
    }

    $filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

    // Create target dir
    if (!file_exists($targetDir))
        @mkdir($targetDir);

    // Remove old temp files    
    if ($cleanupTargetDir && is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))) {
        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

            // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
            if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge) && ($tmpfilePath != "{$filePath}.part")) {
                @unlink($tmpfilePath);
            }
        }

        closedir($dir);
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');


    // Look for the content type header
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]))
        $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];

    if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]))
        $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];

    // Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions didn't support multipart in HTML5
    if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
        if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
            // Open temp file
            $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
            if ($out) {
                // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
                $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

                if ($in) {
                    while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                        fwrite($out, $buff);
                } else
                    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
                fclose($in);
                fclose($out);
                @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else {
        // Open temp file
        $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen("php://input", "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

            fclose($in);
            fclose($out);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    // Check if file has been uploaded
    if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
        // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
        rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);

    }

    // Return JSON-RPC response
    //die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id", "cleanFileName" : "'.$fileName.'"}');

}
```

Mostly its the standard code of custom upload of Plupload. It used to work with $targetDir = "../../../nfsopslag/klachten"; when I had the code outside the controller but after migrating it to the development environment that didn't work anymore.

I tried searching it online but didn't find a sollution. So I am stuck on this. Anyone got ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figured out that the code was firstly incomplete. And secondly we don't want to remove old files so we edited the code by getting rid of this:

```
// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir && is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))) {
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge) && ($tmpfilePath != "{$filePath}.part")) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
} else
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');
```

As you can see it misses some tags. And the variable $cleanupTargetDir was false. Thanks for bearing with me.